# MVC Unit Testing a controller

Tags: unit-testing

I have a controller with the `Authorize` attribute:

```
public CustomerController:Controller  
{
    [Authorize]  
    public ActionResult GetCustomer(int id)  
    {  
        var model=db.Customers.where(c=>c.id==id);
        return View(model);   
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I test a controller with the `Authorize` attribute?

Do we need to get user information like username and password before testing from `HttpContext`?

Are mocks, dependency injection, and inversion of control related to unit testing? If so, can you guys suggest some websites or documents for learning these topics?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some good examples of testing with mocks, DI, IoC, MVC @

http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/source/browse/trunk/Suteki.Shop/Suteki.Shop.Tests/#Suteki.Shop.Tests%2FControllers

The author doesn't use the Authorize attribute but uses custom action filters and roles based security I believe.